# how to view paperclip docx attachment in browser using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have set the disposition property of the method to inline,so i am able to view pdf file in browser but same i want to be done for docx file.But instead of viewing in separate tab the file is downloading.

```html
def download_emp
   send_file @employee_document.document.path,
             filename: @employee_document.document,
             type: @employee_document.document_content_type,
             disposition: 'inline'
 end
```

But i want the docx attachment to be viewed in browser instead of downloading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33308929/2681997

Answer (score 0):

The link where you use the above method, try adding target: "_blank". Below is an example,

`link_to "View", 'url', target: "_blank"`

But downloading a doc file is the default feature of a browser, which cannot be replaced. But giving a try to the above code is worth.

Comment: I tried the above code,its still downloading the docs file instead of viewing in separate tab.By The way thanks for your reply.